# Test rendering of Rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Wrong use of .t method in Rails template such

```
<%= (user.score).t(:context => 'foo') %>
```

Causes an error

```
   undefined method `t' for 46:Fixnum
```

The method was called on number.
Now the question is how can this situation can be tested? Where the test code should live, so all the templates will be tested before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your choice of testing framework. With the Test::Unit stuff that comes with rails your controller and integration tests render views and so should catch this sort of error. Other forms of integration testing, such as cucumber should also pick up such things.

If you use rspec then you can write view specs: specs that test view rendering in isolation.

Lastly if you find yourself with lots of logic in your views that you want to test, you're probably better off extracting that logic into a helper and writing unit tests/specs for that helper.

Comment: Yes I am using Test::Unit. and according to docs it should catch Controller errors but i cant catch this error neither with     assert_response :success nor assert_select 'title', "Page Title!".. the tests pass.

Comment: Then there's is probably something else (is the faulty but of template being rendered at all?) - if view rendering raises an exception in a controller test then the test will fail

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't test the templates itself. But you can test e.g. with [cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) if you get the view results you are expecting. This could be some sort of "template testing".